# Fastest structured way to get max(abc) if a+b+c=30

Tags: summation, products, maximum-principle

What is the fastest and structured way to get maximum of abc if a+b+c=n, say n=30? a,b,c are non-negative and can be non-integer.

Comment: If $a, b, c$ can be any non-integer, you can get $abc$ to be arbitrarily large by having, say $b$ and $c$ be large negative values, and $a$ be the corresponding even larger positive value of $n - b - c$. I assume you need another restriction such as the values being non-negative.

Comment: @JohnOmielan thank you for reminding, they should be non-negative, I will edit it, thanks

Comment: This would have to do with the [arithmetic-geometric mean inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) (*commonly shorthanded as AM-GM inequality*).  The product is maximized when they are all equal, and they are all equal when they are all $\frac{n}{3}$.  In your specific case, $a=b=c=10$ and $abc=1000$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use that $$\frac{a+b+c}{3}\geq \sqrt[3]{abc}$$ so $$10\geq \sqrt[3]{abc}$$